# NSPredicate with Format matching int

Tags: int, nspredicate

Stupid question, I know:

I have this code:

```
MWMarks *fakeMark = [[MWMarks alloc]init];
    fakeMark.sortId=13;
    NSArray * fakeArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:fakeMark];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sortID = %d",13];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [fakeArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSInteger section=[filteredArray indexOfObject:fakeMark];
```

And I would expect 'section' to return 0.
However, it seems the predicate is not satisfied. Can anyone point out my syntax error?

Comment: `fakeMark.sortId=13;` vs `@"sortID = %d"`. `sortId` vs `sortID`. It should give you an error because `sortID` can't be used on `MWMarks` objects.

Comment: Oh my... Thank you so much.